# Need help in understanding the function application operator in haskell

Tags: haskell

This haskell piece of code

```
map ($ 3) [(4+), (10*), (^2), sqrt]
```

gives the output

```
[7.0,30.0,9.0,1.7320508075688772]
```

I know that $ has the lowest precedence and hence the expression to the right of $ is evaluated together. But what I don't understand is how does ($ 3) behave as a function (Because Map takes a function and a list as parameters). I don't understand why each function in the list is applied to 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that `($)` is actually a function:

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
f $ x = f x
```

`($ 3)` is shorthand for `\f -> (f $ 3)`. And its type? Well:

```
3     ::                  Double -- for sake of simplicity
($)   :: (a      -> b) -> a      -> b
($ 3) :: (Double -> b)           -> b
```

So `($ 3)` is a function that takes a function from `Double` to something and applies that function to `3`. Now, if we use `map`, we end up with:

```
map ($ 3) [(4+), (10*), (^2), sqrt]  
 = [($ 3) (4+), ($ 3) (10*), ($ 3)(^2), ($ 3) sqrt]  
 = [(4+) $ 3, (10*) $ 3, (^2) $ 3, sqrt $ 3]  
 = [4 + 3, 10 * 3, 3 ^ 2, sqrt 3]
 = [7, 30, 9, sqrt 3]
```

Comment: If dollar is a function shouldn't the function part be applied be applied to parameters instead of the applying the function to a paramter. I am pretty sure that I have got something wrong :) Just not able to figure what I have got wrong

Comment: @Ashwin err, what? What do you mean by "shouldn't the function part be applied be applied to parameters instead of the applying the function to a paramter"?

Comment: I mean  shouldn't it be other way around. (4+) should take 3 as parameter instead of 3 taking (4+) as parameter?

Comment: No. `($3)` takes `(4+)` as "parameter". Remember `($3)` is a shorthand for `($3) = \f -> f $ 3`, so `($3) (4+)` is `(4+) 3` or `4 + 3`

Answer (score 3):

Let's first review the type signature of `($)`:

```
ghci>> :t ($)
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
```

And definition:

```
($) f x = f x
```

Or:

```
f $ x = f x
```

And above, we have a **section** where we've created a partially applied version of `($)` with the second argument (of type `a`) set as `3`. Now, we know that `3` has type `Num a => a`, so the type signature of our partial application must be `Num a => (a -> b) -> b`.

Next, let's look at each of the functions in our list, each of which will be an argument to ($ 3). As expected, they are functions and it turns out that their type `Num a -> a -> a` is actually more constrained than was required (so we're good). Just to be clear, we can look at what one application would entail:

```
($3) (4+)
```

Which we can rewrite without the section as:

```
($) (4+) 3
```

At which point it's pretty clear from the function definition above how application proceeds.

The last confusing part might be about the type of the list `($3) (4+)` evaluates as `7`, rather than `7.0` in the repl. If we recall that lists are homogeneous and notice that one of the functions in the list, `sqrt`, accepts and returns a floating value, we see that this type enforced for all applications.

Comment: How did you rewrite ($3) (4+) as ($) (4+) 3  ?

Comment: @Ashwin: `($3) = \f -> f $ 3`, or `\f -> ($) f 3` in prefix notation. Replace `f` by `(4+)`.